# Update password form with hashing flask application

Tags: python, flask, bootstrap-4, wtforms

I am taking a subject called webprogramming with python. We learned to use the web framework flask. I am working on the project for this subject and I have created an application using flask. I have made a signup form and login form which is working using SqlAlchemy for creating the database. Now, what I don't figure out is, when I create a user, login and change it's password using an updateform, I can't seem to find a way to be able to login.

The solution I think would be to hash the password, because my login form search for a hashed password, and my update view doesn't create one. So my question is how can I create a hashed password in the user_change view?

Sorry for the stupid question, but I am fairly new to this and I seem to get lost in the wire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with wtforms and sqlalchemy

```
class UpdateAccountForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2,max=20)])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    submit = SubmitField('Update')
```

```
@app.route("/account" , methods=['GET','Post'])
@login_required #This is from flask-login extension
def account():
    form = UpdateAccountForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        current_user.username = form.username.data
        current_user.email = form.email.data
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your account has been updated')
        return redirect(url_for('account'))
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        form.username.data = current_user.username
        form.email.data = current_user.email
    return render_template('account.html', title="Account", form=form)
```

This tutorial maybe help you a lot https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=803Ei2Sq-Zs&

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I followed the vide tutorial you sent, but when I try to update the information and sign out to login again, I receive an error 'Invalid username/password' when I try to log in with the new credentials. Any suggestions

Comment: I got the answer to my questions! The video tutorial was good but didn't mention anything about password hashing, so I added this: hashed_password = generate_password_hash(form.password.data, method='sha256') right under if form.validate_on_submit(): and just editet the password from form.password.data to be hashed_password.

Comment: @AlexanderMyrvold Could please send the final code? I got the same issue with hashed passwords